Update Cells in a Grid - DevExpress Grid Control
How do I loop through each row in this grid and update the price when it finds the "Department" 78102?  I found some links when googled but none showed what I was looking for.
Googled and tried several links
ItemNo  Department  Description StoreNumber Price
1       18331       Home        71832       75.5
2       29653       Lawn        43108       299.95
*3      78102       Plumbing    80001*  
4       44001       Electrical  38913       108.99
5       51836       Wood        41009       39.99


Are you using a DataGridView or a DevExpress XtraGrid control?

To loop over datagridview is like you see below
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        If row.Cells("Department").Value = 78102  Then
            row.Cells("Department").Value = 10
        End If
    Next

But your datasource of the dtagridview like a DataTable, will also be updated, but you still need a UPDATECOMMAND, to send the data to your database or whatever your source is.

Given that the OP used the DevExpress tag, I have to wonder if they are using the DevExpress GridControl/GridView and not the standard .NET DataGridView. If that is the case, your method will not work, as the GridView does not expose a Rows collection.

then he would tell me that it isn't working, but as he didn't, we can assume that it is a normal daragridview and that is why he had problems finding a solution

Yes thank you but as you can see someone down voted it. Correct 5 or 6 posts get credit for it and you can update too
